# Sqlite3 C API number of rows

Tags: c, sqlite

Can I use `SELECT COUNT(*) from tableName` in a C program?

If so, how do I fetch the results? I don't want to use a loop because I only want the number of rows, not the data.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979245/count-number-of-rows-in-a-sqlite-database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you execute the query `SELECT COUNT(*) from tableName`, the result is a table like with other queries, but that result table has only one column and only one row, which contains the count value.

Call `sqlite3_prepare_v2` normally, then `sqlite3_step`, which steps to the first (and only) row.
Call `sqlite3_column_int` to get the value.
The next call to `sqlite3_step` will then return `SQLITE_DONE`.