# How to check if sqlite3 table is empty or not in C without querying for count(*) in the table?

Tags: database, sqlite

I know that the query "select count(*) from table;" will fulfil my requirement, but is there any property / predefined method of SQLite3 to check that a table is empty, or any way through which I can achieve without performing another DB Query?

Comment: You want to **query** whether the table is empty without a **query**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083199/sqlite3-c-api-number-of-rows

There is no external API for this but if you hang on to the prepared statement, it should be plenty fast.