# Get Row count of a Cursor in codename one

Tags: ios, codenameone

Is there any way to retrieve the Row count of a cursor in codename one, where we used in android like cursor.getcount();

Comment: You can refer this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979245/count-number-of-rows-in-a-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

You can use select count to actually count the rows of a query. The main reason for the lack of this functionality is that it isn't available in all platforms (e.g. iOS).